# while statement in Lua in correct way

Tags: while-loop, lua

I try to  increase number in while-loop as in c\c++, but its not correct working, whats wrong?

```
summ=0
i=0
while summ<p do
  summ=p0+aug
  i=i+1
  end
```

Comment: what you mean with "not working"? what is its actual behaviour?

Comment: `summ=p0+aug` produces the same value on every loop iteration, so the loop is infinite.  Did you mean `summ=p0+summ`?

Comment: `p0` and  `aug` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with the provided code.

`p` is `nil` which will cause an error for comparing a nil value with a number value.

`p0` and `aug` are both `nil` which will cause an error for performing arithmetic operations on a nil value

Assuming that `p`, `p0` and `aug` weren't `nil` they would not change value within the while loop. Hence `p0+aug` is a constant. So depending on `p0+aug>p` your loop would either never start, stop after the first run or run forever.

Comment: "So depending on p0+aug>p your loop would either never start, stop"   yes, i has infinity loop there, how can i adding p0+aug in loop? in correct way

Comment: @Vlcvlc I don't know what you want to achieve so I cannot give you a solution. I don't know what p0, aug and p are. You did not provide any definition. but if you have an infinite loop that means you defined those values somewhere outside the provided code snippet. but they cannot change value in the while loop. the sum of two constants is a constant. so your loop condition never changes. please edit your question and add the missing information.